# Can't change the text inside a span using Jquery if else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the text of a `span` when it is clicked depending on the current value it has.

If it is Open  - then set value to Close.

If it is Close - then set value to Open.

```
$('.details_btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).text('Open'){
        $(this).html('Close');
    }else{
        $(this).html('Open');   
    }
});
```

I've got a fiddle of what I've been doing here:

http://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/ch0u1xws/

However, it doesn't seem to ever go back from Close to Open and I'm not sure why. Could someone shed some light on this?

Many thanks

Comment: The 'if' statement is missing the closing ')' but @tymeJV has the full answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is a bit wrong. The `.text()` takes a parameter to set the text, simply call it parameterless to return the current text. So:

```
if($(this).text('Open')){
```

Should be:

```
if($(this).text() == 'Open'){
```

Comment: Thanks man, Worked a charm. Won't be making that mistake again!

Answer (score 1):

The text() function either retrieves or set's the inner text of an element. So to test it's current value you should use:

```
if($(this).text() == "Open")
```

Instead of

```
if($(this).text('Open'))
```

Update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch0u1xws/2/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.details_btn').click(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'Open'){
            $(this).html('Close');
        }else{
            $(this).html('Open');   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the current value, don't provide any parameters to the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, as others have mentioned. But an alternative solution is to pass a function in to manipulate the current value, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.details_btn').click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text == 'Open' ? 'Close' : 'Open';
    });
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.details_btn').click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text == 'Open' ? 'Close' : 'Open';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.details_btn{
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="details_btn">Open</span>
```